# Autohotkey - Key loop making shift key combos not work

Tags: autohotkey

I made a script meant to be spammed on button down , its working but when I wanto use another key combo with [Shift] while holding down the key [Xbutton2] it doesnt work e.g If I wanto press Shift+q it only sends q and its the same for any other keys.

I have been using this script forever but since the Software updated it doesnt seem to work as intended anymore.

```
#ifWinActive ***********

CoordMode,pixel,screen


XButton2::
  Loop  
  {    
SetKeyDelay, 20
if not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P")
  break
 Send  3456789

 sleep +q
 sleep +e
 sleep +f
 sleep +r
 sleep +c
 sleep +q
}
return
```

I just dont understand why any key combo with Shift doesnt work.
I tried adding sleep on the shift keys that I use but it made no diffarence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an asterisk to the front of a hotkey makes it ignore modifier keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

```
*XButton2::
    ;do stuff
    return
```